# Python Tkinter dynamic window not working properly

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to make a financial calculator for myself. Till now I didn't have any major problems, but now I'm stuck and can't figure out what's wrong.
I'm new in this world so don't be mad about my lame coding skills haha!
I made sqlite database with python and in this step I'm trying to pull one column and make button for each value dynamically. I succeed to make that step but my TopLevel window is not resizing how it should. That problem is caused because I want that TopLevel to be opened at same spot as root window, but I can't figure out where I'm making mistake.
Here is my code, I deleted most of unimportant widgets and I made automatic input into db so you guys can check that dynamic button creation. Hope you understood what my problem is about if you need more explanation I will try my best.
Most of code variables are on my language, hope that's not a problem and I don't know why indenting is messed up when I paste the code.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS OTPLATA_NA_RATE
         ([ID] INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,[Opis] text, [Iznos_rate] integer, [Broj_rata] text, [Datum_kupnje] text)''')
c.execute("INSERT INTO OTPLATA_NA_RATE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, "a", 500, "2", "2021-08-10"))
c.execute("INSERT INTO OTPLATA_NA_RATE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, "b", 500, "2", "2021-08-10"))
c.execute("INSERT INTO OTPLATA_NA_RATE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, "c", 500, "2", "2021-08-10"))
c.execute("INSERT INTO OTPLATA_NA_RATE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, "d", 500, "2", "2021-08-10"))
c.execute("INSERT INTO OTPLATA_NA_RATE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, "e", 500, "2", "2021-08-10"))
c.execute("INSERT INTO OTPLATA_NA_RATE VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", (None, "f", 500, "2", "2021-08-10"))


class FinancialCalc:
def __init__(self, master):
    # Start window:
    self.master = master
    self.master.title("Kalkulator troška")
    self.master.geometry("300x300")
    self.master.resizable(False, False)

    self.otplata_na_rate_button = Button(master, text="Otplata na rate", width=15,
                                         command=self.otplata_na_rate_deiconify)
    self.otplata_na_rate_button.place(x=95, y=155)

    # TopLevel window
    self.onr_top = Toplevel()
    self.onr_top.title("Kalkulator troška")
    self.onr_top.withdraw()

def otplata_na_rate_deiconify(self):
    # Otplata_na_rate TopLevel:
    self.master.withdraw()
    self.onr_top.deiconify()
    self.onr_top.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (self.master.deiconify(), self.onr_top.withdraw()))
    # Pull data from db and creating dynamic buttons (depends how many items are in db)
    c.execute('SELECT Opis FROM OTPLATA_NA_RATE')
    lista_opisa_rata = list()
    for opis in c:
        lista_opisa_rata.append(opis[0])
    kolona = 0
    red = 0
    for opis in lista_opisa_rata:
        rata_button = Button(self.onr_top, text=opis, width=10)
        rata_button.grid(row=red, column=kolona, pady=5, padx=5)
        kolona += 1
        if kolona == 3:
            red += 1
            kolona = 0

    w = self.onr_top.winfo_width()
    h = self.onr_top.winfo_height()
    x = self.master.winfo_x()
    y = self.master.winfo_y()
    print(w, h)
    self.onr_top.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (w, h, x, y))


 root = Tk()
 my_gui = FinancialCalc(root)
 root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `self.master.winfo_rootx()` and `self.master.winfo_rooty()`? Also you don't need the `%dx%d` inside the `"%dx%d+%d+%d"`.

Comment: @TheLizzard Hey mate, coordinates and positioning are fine, don't have problem with that, but height and width of TopLevel window is problem. Somehow both is 200,200 whole time, but I didn't set that geometry parameters

Comment: Just use `self.onr_top.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")`. You don't need to specify the width/height each time you call `.geometry`. If it works I will write an explanation for why your method doesn't work.

Comment: @TheLizzard Omg mate that works! What was wrong with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you called `.winfo_width()` just after creating new widgets in the window. That sends events to expand the window but they aren't shown until `tkinter` has had time to update.

In your code you could have added `self.onr_top.update()` just before the `self.onr_top.winfo_width()` and it might have worked.

Another solution would have been to use `winfo_reqwidth()` instead of `winfo_width()`.

But the easiest solution is to use:

```py
self.onr_top.geometry(f"+{x}+{y}")
```

When using `.geometry`, you can specify the `widthxheight` or `widthxheight+x+y` or just `+x+y`

Comment: The [docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) would suggest using `.update_idletasks()` if one did it that way instead of `.update()`

Comment: Thanks mate for explanation, you just saved me hours of trying to fix it, as I did before I decided to ask here :P. Life saver!

Comment: @Matiiss That will also work but it's rare that `.update()` will cause troubles that `.update_idletasks()` wouldn't.

Comment: @TheLizzard interestingly in the [docs](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) it was said that `.update()` might cause some unexpected looping (which I have never experienced) but also there was some other article about why using `.update()` is bad, `.update_idletasks` is however slightly different, it doesn't update everything so there is less risk?

Comment: @Matiiss The only problem with `.update` is that if you call `.update` from a function it can send an even and fire the same function (if it's binded). Most of the time it's fine, but sometimes (like once in my code), the code manipulates sensitive variables and you might not expect them to change.

Comment: @Matiiss Also it can cause `RecursionError`s because the `.update` can calls a function with `.update` which can call a function with `.update`, ...

Comment: @TheLizzard I guess that is the mentioned "looping", but would it be better to use `.update_idletasks()` then, could they raise `RecursionError`?

Comment: @Matiiss I am yet to find a list of technical differences between `.update` and `.update_idletasks`. From what I have read `.update_idletasts` only handles events that aren't caused by the user/programmer. But I am not even 50% sure about that. And I try to discourage both methods but sometimes they can be very useful.